# Python How to find the max element in a list

Tags: python, list, max, element

I'm trying to find the maximum rainfall from a data file. The precipitation column in the [4] element in a 1340 line long file. 
Here's an example of a line of data from the file:

```
Date,Day,High T,Low T,Precip,Snow,Snow Depth
1/1/10,1,41,19,0,0,5
```

Here's the loop I'm trying to find the max_precip:

```
for line in fo:
    max_precip = max(line.split(",")[4])
```

Any help or guidance here would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

Comment: Did you consider numpy to read in your data and process it?

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to apply this to *all* lines, and you'll need to convert the precipitation value to integer first:

```
 max_precip = max(fo, key=lambda line: int(line.split(',')[4]))
```

This returns the *whole line* containing the maximum precipitation. I'm assuming you already removed the header line.

Note that you may want to look at the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) to handle the comma-splitting for you.

To get *just* the precipitation maximum and ignore everything else, use a generator expression:

```
 max_precip = max(int(line.split(',')[4]) for line in fo)
```

Demo:

```
>>> fo = '''\
... 1/1/10,1,41,19,0,0,5
... 1/2/10,1,38,18,2,0,6
... 1/3/10,1,43,17,1,0,6
... '''.splitlines()
>>> max(fo, key=lambda line: int(line.split(',')[4]))
'1/2/10,1,38,18,2,0,6'
>>> max(int(line.split(',')[4]) for line in fo)
2
```

Comment: It gives me a syntax error when I try this. Sorry I am brand new to programming. I'm not seeing what part of your code makes the loop apply to all the lines.

Comment: @Hense: I pass in `fo`, a sequence of lines.

Comment: @Hense: I tested again, I don't have a syntax error. Perhaps you forgot to close a parenthesis on the line before?

Comment: @Hense you said you are new to programming so i am suspecting you are copying the example as it is in your editor. Whereas the lines starting with >>> identify commands to be run at the Python console prompt. So if indeed you are copying into your editor remove all the >>>.

Comment: @JoErNanO that comment was made before I added the demo session to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to find the maximum rainfall from a data file.

If that is what you want, you may want to pre-process your data, before passing to the built-in `max` function.

```
max_precip = max(int(line.split(',')[4]) for line in fo)
```